# Test code such that no function calls kwarg as an arg

Tags: python, python-2.7

In python, it is possible to check whether a function makes function calls where named arguments are called as positional arguments?

For example:

```
def a(pos_arg, nam_arg=None, nam_arg2=None):
    return "whatever"

def b():
    return a(1, 2, nam_arg2="whatever")
```

Here, the function b calls the function a, but the second argument is a named argument, which is being called as a positional argument. This might cause confusing problems when object inheritance comes into play.

Better would have been:

```
def b():
    return a(1, nam_arg=2, nam_arg2="whatever")
```

For testing purposes (as this is generally bad code in my project), I would like to find out whether the function `b()` makes such calls.

Is this possible in python?

Comment: why is it a bad call when the function takes keyword arguments?

Comment: Because upon changing the function ```a()``` of such a function (for instance through overriding it in a superclass), the position of named arguments might change. See for instance this bug which cost me days of work: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/24911

Comment: so you just want to see if any functions in your source are calling other functions using keywords args?

Comment: No, if they are calling other functions keywords args as positional args.

Comment: Where in your example is that happening? Are we talking about `2`?

Comment: Python passes both keyword and positional arguments to the function as a dictionary and there is no way to distinguish which one was used.

For debugging purposes you can check `inspect.stack` function which returns the list of all the callers of the function.

Comment: @Padriac, yes we are talking about that 2. I tried to clarify the question further.

Comment: Do you know the function you are looking for or do you want to check every single fucntion?

Comment: I want to check every single function.

Answer (score 2):

You tagged your question as python-2.7 but for the sake of future viewers I would say that in python 3 we now have [keyword-only arguments](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3102/) feature which allows to define a function like that:

```
def func(pos_arg, *, kw_only_arg):
    pass
```

In that case `kw_only_arg` is allowed to be used only as keyword argument.
If you can't use python 3 then there is a recipe that can help you with that:
http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578993-keyword-only-arguments-in-python-2x/